# How to go about storing and accessing of images inside the blog using LAMP stack?

Tags: html, mysql, laravel, database-design

I want to create a technical blog using LAMP stack (Laravel Framework). I would like to know what is the best way of storing and accessing images inside a blog content?

There is one way of doing this that I could think of:
(1) Storing the images as a file and then accessing those images using path which is specified as the src attribute of the  tag which could be the part of content fetched from the database.

Answer (score 0):

The most correct thing would be to store it in storage. Laravel provides a powerful filesystem abstraction thanks to the wonderful [Flysystem](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem) PHP package by Frank de Jonge. The Laravel Flysystem integration provides simple to use drivers for working with local filesystems, Amazon S3, and Rackspace Cloud Storage. Even better, it's amazingly simple to switch between these storage options as the API remains the same for each system.

That is, you can store them locally on your LAMP server or you can use an external server for that. Both ways are good, however it depends on your needs.

You have to store the relative path in the database. i.e. `/path/to/image.jpg`

Then to show these files with the Facade `Storage` you can show them easily.

If you are using the local driver, this will typically just prepend `/storage` to the given path and return a relative URL to the file. If you are using the s3 or rackspace driver, the fully qualified remote URL will be returned:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$url = Storage::url('image.jpg');
```